# How to show user only available field of model?

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-queryset

I have two models car and booking. A car is `ForeignKey` field in booking model if car is booked then in car list its still showing available . I have is_available_car model field in car model `default=True`.
If car is booked then it will not show till it's unbooked. 
i am haviing booking form in car is foreign key and after user booked the car its still showing the car .
Help me please. Thank you.

**Model**

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    booking_name = models.CharField(max_length=240, null=False)
    customer_name = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='book_customers' )
    book_car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='book_car')
    booking_start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False)
    booking_end_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    rental_price = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    times_pick = models.TimeField(blank=True)
    is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.booking_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("buggy_app:detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

**Views .py**

```
class BookingView(FormView):
 template_name = 'buggy_app/booking.html'
 form_class = BookingForm
 models = Booking
 def form_valid(self, form):
    form.save()
    return super(BookingView, self).form_valid(form)

 success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # kwargs['car'] is the car booking now!
    try:
        kwargs['car'] = Car.objects.get(id=self.request.GET.get('car', ''))
    except (Car.DoesNotExist, ValueError):
        kwargs['car'] = None
    return super(BookingView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

def get_initial(self):
    initial = super(BookingView, self).get_initial()
    if 'car' in self.request.GET:
        try:
            initial['book_car'] = Car.objects.get(id=self.request.GET['car'])
        except (Car.DoesNotExist, ValueError):
            pass
    return initial

 class CarListView(ListView):
  context_object_name = 'cars'
  model = models.Car

def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super(CarListView, self).get_queryset()
    qs = qs.filter(is_available_car=True)
    return qs
```

Comment: @lad help me to solve this issue

Comment: Get `Car.id` from `Book` relation. Change it value to `True` and save `Car` instance.

Comment: @mauro can you tell me the code ?

Comment: @Shko you must show your code, what have you tried, to we help you.

Comment: @Mauro  okay ill post it here

Comment: @Mauro Check now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view that receive the booking request, get the identifier of the `Car` and change its is_available_car attribute:

`views.py`

```
class BookingView(FormView):
    ...
    def form_valid(self, form):
        car_id = self.request.GET.get('car', '')
        car = Car.objects.get(id=car_id)
        car.is_available_car = False
        car.save()
        form.save()
        return super(BookingView, self).form_valid(form)
```

and in the car listing you should filter the cars that have `is_available_car=False`

Comment: @Shko this is the solution!

Comment: @Shko you should post your view code that receive the booking request, to see where to insert the code.

Comment: its my views.py

Comment: @Shko i edited my answer with the code snippet. I hope this will help

Comment: @yusef thankyouu thankyouuuuu so much i was asking this question from a week . And everyone vote down the question and didnt give me the solution . Thankyouu really

Comment: @MauroBaraldi help me

Comment: @Shko, it was working and you marked it as correct. may be you broke it by changing something. At least Consider updating the question and elaborate.

Comment: @YusefBH i had copied it run it but after booking it still showing cars in list. i didnt add any other stufs. while i correct it . i didnt put it in my code .

Comment: After booking a car you got redirected to the `index` page or the booking `form` appears again?

Comment: @MauroBaraldi help me

Comment: @Shko after booking a car you got redirected to the `index` page or the booking `form` appears again?

Comment: Redirecting to index page

Comment: In your views.py file the `form_valid` function is not like in my answer above!

Comment: @yusef sorry i am asking a question not from this topic. I am having a calender and time widget.if user select date and time how to send that date and time to forms . for eg . user select date and time after that how do i redirect it to booking form and save it in date and time ?

Comment: Please, consider asking another question with your `form` code and details, and don't change older questions. consider remarking this as correct.